# How do you write a good stored procedure for update?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to write a stored procedure (SQL server 2008r2), say I have a table:

```
person

Columns:
Id int (pk)
Date_of_birth date not null
Phone int  allow null
Address int allow null
Name nvarchat(50) not null
```

Sample data:
`Id=1,Date_of_birth=01/01/1987,phone=88888888,address=null,name='Steve'`

Update statement in Stored procedure, assume
The parameters are already declare:
`Update person set
Date_of_birth=@dob,phone=@phone,address=@address,name=@name where id=@id`

The table has a trigger to log any changes.
Now I have an asp.net update page for updating the above person table

The question is, if user just want to update address='apple street' , the above update statement will update all the fields but not check if the original value = new value, then ignore this field and then check the next field. So my log table will log all the event even the columns are not going to be updated.

At this point, my solutions

1. Select all the value by id and store them into local variables.
   Using if-else check and generate the update statement. At last,
   dynamically run the generated SQL (sp_executesql)
2. Select all the value by id and store them into local variables.
   Using if-else check and update each field seperately:

`If @dob <> @ori_dob

Begin

Update person set date_of_birth=@dob where id=@id

End`

May be this is a stupid question but please advice me if you have better idea, thanks!

Comment: Is your log table populated using a trigger on person?  If so you might want to consider checking each column there instead of in the update procedure.

Comment: What's the issue if the user is only updating one of the columns? Why not let him update everything and if one of the columns being updated already has the same value; let it be updated as well.

Comment: @pilotcam I see. This is another solution for me, thanks.

Comment: @lcarus My log table will have 5 rows added when updating 'person' table.

Comment: @user1439709 why don't you have an Audit table with the exact same structure as the source table and insert a row per/update instead of a row per column updated? Unless you have a valid business reason to do this, let me tell you that your approach is rather unorthodox and smells bad to me.

Comment: The trigger can compare values from the `inserted` and `deleted` tables to determine what has changed.  It cannot tell what was overwritten with the same value.

Comment: @lcarus Yup, I think this is a bad idea too, that's why I posted this question and asking normally how do you make a stored procedure for update if audit log is applied to this situation.
This is my audit log trigger:
http://www.nigelrivett.net/AuditTrailTrigger.html

Comment: @HABO So in my case, how do I block other update and just update the "address"? I am newbie on writing trigger:(

Comment: I don't understand - your trigger inserts changed columns only. See `where` condition on dynamic sql.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Thanks for the reply. Yes, the trigger only log the changes, but I was wondering if there is any better coding than the following stored procedure
`CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_UpdateTrigger
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @i int
 ,@j int
 ,@s varchar(10)
 ,@t varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
 Update trigtest Set
   s=@s
   ,t=@t
 Where i=@i and j=@j
END
GO`

Comment: In my opinion you should not worry about excessive inserting because trigger (as you have shown it) will only insert columns where value was actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an answer to a comment by the OP and does not address the original question.  It would, however, be a rather ugly comment.*

You can use a statement like this to find the changes to `Address` within an `UPDATE` trigger:

```
select i.Id, d.Address as OldAddress, i.Address as NewAddress
  from inserted as i inner join
    deleted as d on d.Id = i.Id
  where d.Address <> i.Address
```

One such statement would be needed for each column that you want to log.

You could accumulate the results of the `SELECT`s into a single table variable, then summarize the results for each `Id`.  Or you can use `INSERT`/`SELECT` to save the results directly to your log table.